# How to based on value show another iin Tornado template?

Tags: python, templates, tornado

At the moment I am printing nation of player like `<p>{{data['nation']}}</p>`. I want to change to for every nation I can put different image( Images are in `../images` folder with names like: `american.png`, `british.png` ... and nation from data are `1` for `american`, `2` for `british`). How to based on value show another image for nation ? I am using Tornado template.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but you can define dictionary to map one data to another. You can do it inside template using `{% set a=1 %}` syntax:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    {% set map_img = {1:'american.png', 2:'british.png'} %} 
</head>
<body>
    <p>{{data['nation']}} -> {{map_img[data['nation']]}}</p></br>
    <img src="{{static_url("images/")}}{{map_img[data['nation']]}}"/>   
</body>
</html>
```

But it looks like a bad design for me to declare such a dictionary inside template itself. Consider mapping inside your application and passing result to render method together with other arguments.